# How to open a chrome extension in a new tab with the session of salesforce org?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, salesforce

I am creating one salesforce chrome extension. I want to open this extension in a new tab instead of a popup. I am able to open the extension in new tab but not able to get the login details from salesforce.

In background.js file not able to set the port connection.

Tried connecting the session in background.js but adding it to background.js will not solve the purpose.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am creating one salesforce chrome extension. I want to open this extension in a new tab instead of a popup. I am able to open the extension in new tab but not able to get the login details from salesforce.